# Confusion in was and were: The diameter length of X,Y,Z was/were 4,5,6 respectively

Tags: grammar, verb-agreement

I am confused with the usage of was vs were in the following sentence:

The length of diameter of three plates X, Y, Z was/were 4, 5, 6 respectively.

I am not sure which one is correct: was or were.

Should it be "was" since it's referring to diameter?

Comment: I'd rephrase to *The **diameter lengths** of three plates X, Y, Z **were** 4, 5, 6 respectively,* where it seems pretty clear-cut that we'd naturally use the plural form.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. You might find [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com) more suited to questions like this. I don't think you need to include "length" at all. The sentence could be phrased **"The diameters of the three plates X,Y,Z were 4,5,6 respectively."** Your difficulty is because you've used "length of diameter", which is singular, but you have three values (plural).

Comment: Toss out "lengths" entirely.  "The diameter**s** of **the** three plates X, Y, **and** Z were 4, 5, **and** 6, respectively."

Answer (score 1):

I guess that the sentence is the answer to question.  So it is impossible to be sure sure whether the answer quoted is to a question, whose wording we do not have.  But I should have said "The diameters of the three plates, X, Y and Z, **were** 4,5 and 6, respectively". The word 'length' is superfluous:  a diameter **is a length.  Better still, "The three plates X,Y and Z **had** diameters of 4,5 and 6, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence is constructed poorly, but the correct conjugation is "was" because the subject in the sentence is 'length', not 'diameter' nor 'plates'.

Comment: As comments above indicate, it's truly better for comprehension to calrify the idea and remove 'length' from the sentence.